# Javascript : Retrieve an item value from SP List

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

Before explaining my problem, I give you the context.

I've made an first page that will display a "Marquee" message (message that will scroll horizontally).

I would like to make possible to edit the "Marquee message" from an another page.
So, I've created an other page with a textarea and a button.
When I write a text and click on the button, an item is created in a list called "MarqueeList".

That list contain only the last message that we create : my script delete all the items before add a new one.

My problem is that I would to get that message item, using a script from the page that contain the marquee, and store it into a variable.

I've tried many and any script, but it doesn't work.

If someone could help me, or advise me to the good way?

Thanks a lot

Here is my code with API REST :

```
function retrieveItem(){
$.ajax({
    url : "<siteURL>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MarqueeMessage')/items?$orderby=ID desc&$top=1",
    type : "GET",
    data : data,
    headers:  
    {  
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
        "IF-MATCH": "*",  
        "X-HTTP-Method": null  
    },  
    cache: false,  
    success : onSuccess,
    error : onError
});

function onSuccess(data){   
        var item = data.d.results;  
        var msg = item.Message;
        alert(msg);
}

function onError(error)  {  
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}    
}
```

Comment: which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint 2013

Comment: Check below answer, try it and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharePoint REST API to get the list item and use its column values to show on the page.

Endpoint:

```
<siteURL>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items
```

If you want to get the latest created item (single list item) then you can use:

```
<siteURL>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items?$orderby=ID desc&$top=1
```

**References**:

1. [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)
2. [CRUD Operation On List Items Using REST API Services In SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/)

**Update from Comments**:

You can try using below code:

```
function retrieveItem() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "<siteURL>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MarqueeMessage')/items?$orderby=ID desc&$top=1",
        type : "GET",
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(data) {
            var listItems = data.d.results;
            if(listItems && listItems.length) {
                var msg = listItems[0].Message; // Here you need to use the internal name of your "Message" column
                console.log(msg);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {  
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

You can get the internal name of your Message column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try :)

Comment: Sure, try it and comment here if you come across any error or issue.

Comment: I've tried something, I edit my post with the code. It doesn't work, I haven't got the alert. I'm not very sure about what I have done :/

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console? If Yes, please add the error message to your question. Also try the code given in my updated answer.

Comment: I'm getting an error at the line 12 > "data : data,". The error = "Uncaught ReferenceError : data is not defined"

Comment: Yes, there were some syntactical errors in your code. please try the code given in my answer.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on data

Comment: Have you used the exact code as given in my answer? At which line you are getting this error? inside `success` function?

Comment: Yes i've the exact code as you give in your answer. No, i'm getting this error at "date : data,"

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo mistake. please remove `data:data` from your code. check updated answer now.

Comment: I'm now getting the error "Failed to load resource : the server responded with a status of 400(Bad Request). A potentially dangerous Request. Past value was detected from the client (&lt;)". So no more error about the script, but I think it's because the path that is going to the list

Comment: replace `<siteURL>` token in my code with the actual SharePoint site URL, like what you were using before: `http://portail-wilointec/dev/th/_api/web/lists...`.

Comment: I've replaced <siteURL> by the real text url and it's work. I'm getting the message in the console well! Thanks a lot Ganesh ! :D

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance the list is in a different domain than the page with marquee?

If that is the case, you need to change the "Context" object and point it to the site containing the list.

For Rest API :

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
executor.executeAsync(
  {
    url: appweburl +
          "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists?@target='" +
          hostweburl + "'",
    method: "GET",
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
  }
)
```

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

if you are using JSOM:

```
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
});


// Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(<app web url>);
// Illustrates how to use the executeAsync method.
// Function to prepare and issue the request to get
//  SharePoint data.
       function execCrossDomainRequest() {
   var executor;

       // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
       executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

       // Issue the call against the host web.
       // To get the title using REST we can hit the endpoint:
       //      app_web_url/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/title?@target='siteUrl'
       // The response formats the data in the JSON format.
       // The functions successHandler and errorHandler attend the
       //      success and error events respectively.
       executor.executeAsync(
           {
               url:
                   appweburl +
                   "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/title?@target='" +
                   hostweburl + "'",
                   method: "GET",
                   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                   success: successHandler,
                   error: errorHandler
                }
            );
        }

       // Function to handle the success event.
       // Prints the host web's title to the page.
       function successHandler(data) {
           var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);

           document.getElementById("HostwebTitle").innerHTML =
               "<b>" + jsonObject.d.Title + "</b>";
       }

       // Function to handle the error event.
       // Prints the error message to the page.
       function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
           document.getElementById("HostwebTitle").innerText =
               "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage;
       }
```

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/dn735924(v%3Doffice.15)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! No, they are all on the same domain. I will try your solution.